# Is there a way to set UILaunchStoryboardName property of info.plist using SCRIPT in iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to change the launch screen using some script.
Don't know if it is possible or not.

I have seen in HBL mobile app their launch screen changes every single day.
And they are not using 2nd viewController maybe, because the first white screen time is almost zero in HBL app.

Comment: You cannot ,are the launch screen dynamic. If what you are seeing *appears* to change, it is certain that the app uses a blank LaunchScreen and is written to show the first view controller before any other processing is done.

Comment: @DonMag Yeah I read in most of post that you can't achieve it but I am curious about HBL mobile app they have the first screen(Launch Screen) appearing for milli seconds and then some custom VC(launch screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the "HBL mobile app" but it's a very common technique.

Make the first VC as "light" as possible so it loads and displays almost instantly. Maybe it starts with just a label and an activity spinner.

Once it is visible - such as in `viewDidAppear` - that's when you start any processing such as downloading data, loading graphics, etc.